# Loading HTML page into container with java from a page within the container

Tags: java, html, single-page-application

I'm new to coding and this is my first time here so go easy :)

also please feel free to tell me this is a stupid way of achieving the desired effect.

I'm developing the company intranet page and have started loading pages into a container within the index.php page. which works fine!

The problem I have is this same method isn't working for buttons I create within the pages getting loaded into the container.

Example:

```
index.html

       <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#" id="load_HR"> HR</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" id="load_FAQ"> FAQ</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" id="load_info"> Info</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" id="load_directory"> Directory</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#load_HR").on("click", function() {
    $("#content").load("HR.html");
});
    $("#load_FAQ").on("click", function() {
    $("#content").load("FAQ.php");
});
    $("#load_Info").on("click", function() {
    $("#content").load("info.html");
});
    $("#load_directory").on("click", function() {
    $("#content").load("directory.php");
});
});

<div id="content"></div>
```

This is how my Navbar buttons load pages into the Container, this works fine.

Now I want to load a page within say the HR.html page into the container that's currently occupied by the HR.html page.

looks easy, sounds complicated and I'm going round in circles.

Please help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the JQuery .load() functions tries to do a XMLHttpRequest
which results in the following error

`cannot load Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.`

Try using plain JS it worked for me.

`$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#load_HR").on("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="HR.html" ></object>';
});`

So your code should look something like this

```
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#" id="load_HR"> HR</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" id="load_FAQ"> FAQ</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" id="load_info"> Info</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" id="load_directory"> Directory</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#load_HR").on("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="HR.html" ></object>';
});
    $("#load_FAQ").on("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="FAQ.php" ></object>';
});
    $("#load_Info").on("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="info.html" ></object>';
});
    $("#load_directory").on("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="directory.php" ></object>';
});
});

<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your Help DevKimo!

I eventually worked out that I could get around my problem by adding a function to the page that loaded into the container.

Answer (score 0):

I found my jQuery Answer:

by adding this function to the page that loaded into the content container
for example when I loaded the HR.html page:

```
function loadbenefits() {
    $('#hrContent').load('CompanyBenefits.html');
}
```

then make a button that loaded the new page into the container with the onClick(="loadbenefits()" like so:

```
<button onClick="loadbenefits()" class="btn" type="button" value="Go"> Some Text </button>
```